# Android set visibility not working

Tags: android, xml, visibility

I have a `TextView` and an `Image` within my `LinearLayout` if a phone value gets passed through to the activity through an intent, then I set the visibility of the layout that contains the text and image to visible.

In my code the layout shows up, but the text and image don't even though they are set to visible in the same check that makes the layout visible. I've added my xml and the Java code that sets visibility in my code.

```
if(extras.getString("phone") != null){
    Log.d("PHONE VISIBLE", "phone made clayout visible");
    contactsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    phoneLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mPhone = extras.getString("phone");
    Log.d("places got phone", mPhone.toString());
    phone.setText(mPhone);
}
```

Here's my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contactsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contactsLabel"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="contact"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/phoneLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phoneImage"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_phone"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            tools:text="phoneNumber"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emailImage"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_email"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            tools:text="email"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your first `TextView` has a `layout_width` of `match_parent`. This is pushing the rest of the Views out of the horizontal `LinearLayout` they're in.

Comment: can u please attach one image or SS so provide you better solution

Answer (score 1):

As Mike said

Change contactsLabel as follows:

```
TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contactsLabel"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="contact"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your contactsLayout orientation to vertical then you can able to see the phonelayout.

Answer (score 0):

replace your xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contactsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contactsLabel"
            android:background="#F4F3F3"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="contact"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phoneLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phoneImage"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                tools:text="phoneNumber"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emailImage"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                tools:text="email"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Make sure your "phone" container in which you have set phone is visible**

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
      contactsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      phoneLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      mPhone = extras.getString("phone");
      phone.setText(mPhone);
}
```